# ClamAV clamscan not scanning for infected files present inside an archived file

Tags: windows, clamav, clam

I am testing ClamAV to detect viruses on machine.

I am running
`clamscan -r -i "Path to folder containing archive that has infected file"`

It fails to detect the infected file present inside the archive file.
If I have the infected file outside of the zip, it is detecting the file.

I have created clamd.conf / clamav.conf in the scanner folder that has scan-archive set to yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your zip file might be bigger than default values.
Add these options as well for running the scan.

```
--max-filesize=#n
Extract and scan at most #n bytes from each archive. You may pass the value in kilobytes in format xK or xk, or megabytes in format xM or xm, where x is a number. This option protects your system against DoS attacks (default: 25 MB, max: <4 GB)

--max-scansize=#n
Extract and scan at most #n bytes from each archive. The size the archive plus the sum of the sizes of all files within archive count toward the scan size. For example, a 1M uncompressed archive containing a single 1M inner file counts as 2M toward max-scansize. You may pass the value in kilobytes in format xK or xk, or megabytes in format xM or xm, where x is a number. This option protects your system against DoS attacks (default: 100 MB, max: <4 GB)

--max-files=#n
Extract at most #n files from each scanned file (when this is an archive, a document or another kind of container). This option protects your system against DoS attacks (default: 10000)
```

refs: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/clamscan.1.html